# Is it possible to set a limit on the number of cores to be used in Cuda programming for a given code?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, nvidia

Assume I have Nvidia K40, and for some reason, I want my code only uses portion of the Cuda cores(i.e instead of using all 2880 only use 400 cores for examples), is it possible?is it logical to do this either? 
In addition, is there any way to see how many cores are being using by GPU when I run my code? In other words, can we check during execution, how many cores are being used by the code, report likes "task manger" in Windows or top in Linux?

Comment: No, pretty much none of this is possible; it does not make sense either. Why would you want to do anything like that, anyway? The closest you can get to using a portion of cores is deliberately under-utilizing the device by not launching enough threads. Needless to say, this is the exact opposite to what most people are trying to do.

Comment: As far as I know, the number of SMs which execute a kernel is limited by the number of thread blocks you launch. As of this comment, thread blocks do not migrate from SM to SM.

Comment: It's uncommon, but i am pretty sure cuda reserves the right to switch the SM a thread block is assigned to. I think this could happen if one SM finishes very early and another SM is highly loaded.

Comment: I don't think you can control the mapping between the threadblocks and SMs. But at the very least, you can know which SM executes which threadblock.

Comment: @void_ptr, you can have a couple of independent kernels. What I saw with 30 SMs and kernels with 30 blocks is full occupation of GPU. Really, this is a bit faster to execute 30 blocks at 30 SMs against 30/4=8 SMs. But if you run one kernel this way, the second will be awaiting for the finishing. But loading of SM with 1 block is not effective, so such run too. But GPU can't know whether we are going to run another kernel after this one with 30 blocks or not - whether it will be effective to spread it onto all SMs or not. So some manual way to say this should exist

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but the concept in a way goes against fundamental best practices for cuda. Not to say it couldn't be useful for something. For example if you want to run multiple kernels on the same GPU and for some reason want to allocate some number of Streaming Multiprocessors to each kernel. Maybe this could be beneficial for L1 caching of a kernel that does not have perfect memory access patterns (I still think for 99% of cases manual shared memory methods would be better).

How you could do this, would be to access the ptx identifiers %nsmid and %smid and put a conditional on the original launching of the kernels. You would have to only have 1 block per Streaming Multiprocessor (SM) and then return each kernel based on which kernel you want on which SM's.

I would warn that this method should be reserved for very experienced cuda programmers, and only done as a last resort for performance. Also, as mentioned in my comment, I remember reading that a threadblock could migrate from one SM to another, so behavior would have to be measured before implementation and could be hardware and cuda version dependent. However, since you asked and since I do believe it is possible (though not recommended), here are some resources to accomplish what you mention.

PTS register for SM index and number of SMs...
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/#identifiers

and how to use it in a cuda kernel without writing ptx directly...
https://gist.github.com/allanmac/4751080

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, whether it works with the K40, but for newer Ampere GPUs there is the MIG Multi-Instance-GPU feature to partition GPUs.

https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/mig-user-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know such methods, but would like to get to know.

**As to question 2**, I suppose sometimes this can be useful. When you have complicated execution graphs, many kernels, some of which can be executed in parallel, you want to load GPU fully, most effectively. But it seems on its own GPU can occupy all SMs with single blocks of one kernel. I.e. if you have a kernel with 30-blocks grid and 30 SMs, this kernel can occupy entire GPU. I believe I saw such effect. Really this kernel will be faster (maybe 1.5x against 4 256-threads blocks per SM), but this will not be effective when you have another work.

GPU can't know whether we are going to run another kernel after this one with 30 blocks or not - whether it will be more effective to spread it onto all SMs or not. So some manual way to say this should exist

**As to question 3**, I suppose GPU profiling tools should show this, Visual Profiler and newer Parallel Nsight and Nsight Compute. But I didn't try. This will not be Task manager, but a statistics for kernels that were executed by your program instead.

As to possibility to move thread blocks between SMs when necessary,
@ChristianSarofeen, I can't find mentions that this is possible. Quite the countrary,

> Each CUDA block is executed by one streaming multiprocessor (SM) and
> cannot be migrated to other SMs in GPU (except during preemption,
> debugging, or CUDA dynamic parallelism).
> https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-refresher-cuda-programming-model/

Although starting from some architecture there is such thing as preemption. As I remember NVidia advertised it in the following way. Let's say you made a game that run some heavy kernels (say for graphics rendering). And then something unusual happened. You need to execute some not so heavy kernel as fast as possible. With preemption you can unload somehow running kernels and execute this high priority one. This increases execution time (of this high pr. kernel) a lot.

I also found such thing:

> CUDA Graphs present a new model for work submission in CUDA. A graph
> is a series of operations, such as kernel launches, connected by
> dependencies, which is defined separately from its execution. This
> allows a graph to be defined once and then launched repeatedly.
> Separating out the definition of a graph from its execution enables a
> number of optimizations: first, CPU launch costs are reduced compared
> to streams, because much of the setup is done in advance; second,
> presenting the whole workflow to CUDA enables optimizations which
> might not be possible with the piecewise work submission mechanism of
> streams.
> https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-graphs

I do not believe kernels invocation take a lot of time (of course in case of a stream of kernels and if you don't await for results in between). If you call several kernels, it seems possible to send all necessary data for all kernels while the first kernel is executing on GPU. So I believe NVidia means that it runs several kernels in parallel and perform some smart load-balancing between SMs.

Comment: The following article looks interesting: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpe.4409
"Maximizing the GPU resource usage by reordering concurrent kernels submission".

A bit strange approach, but report speed ups around 2x

Comment: And this one too: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3453953.3453972?casa_token=DbeuyW7SuScAAAAA:FxaFwn3_LbfhW-dHByNpihciUuJxg5gawza2T6VPVA5enPBy2lv1_hhC5dk85fk4YKCBeRpYIItA "Demystifying the Placement Policies of the NVIDIA GPU Thread Block Scheduler for Concurrent Kernels"
They state that each SM can process thread blocks from different kernels simultaneously. This decreases the problem of loading of all SMs with single blocks, but still keeps place for non-optimal scheduling